# mongoengine: how to query on a non-ascii StringField in EmbeddedDocumentListField

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

when I run a query like

```
answerSheet = answerSheet.subAnswerSheets.get(
        title=subquiz.title)
```

when my title is non-ascii, I get encode error on this method of EmbeddedDocumentList class in datastructures.py of mongoengine:

```
@classmethod
def __match_all(cls, i, kwargs):
    items = kwargs.items()
    return all([
        getattr(i, k) == v or str(getattr(i, k)) == v for k, v in items
    ])
```

and when I remove str cast, it works fine. so is it my fault or source code needs some change?

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will work for you:

```
title = subquiz.title.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
```

Comment: And use it while creating data also  so that , this will not cause issue further.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush S. Wanare , but sorry, it did not work. while creating data it cause to save empty string instead of non-ascii with no error. and when making query, if the stored strings are non-ascii, again same UnicodeEncode error will raise.
I think this problem is just about EmbeddedDocumentListField, because it never happens in simple Document Inherited Class.